# How to add a letter next to an Image in a formula field for Color Blind users?

Tags: image-formula, lightning-progressindicator

On a related list, the risk is shown as a red, orange or green flag. We can have multiples records.
This is an issue for users that are color blind as they cannot see the difference between the lines.

[image: Risk Indicator]
Request is if we can add next to the flag a value
Red flag: R
Orange flag: O
Green flag: G

The current formula is as follow :

```
    IMAGE( CASE( Risk__c,
"Low", "/img/samples/flag_green.gif",
"Medium", "/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif",
"High", "/img/samples/flag_red.gif",
"/s.gif"), "Competitive Risk")
```

The formula is not working by adding a Letter.
Do you have an idea or a workaround for this request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a Text formula you can divide logic to first display the image and then add the letter after the image. Between the image and the letter you can also add a whitespace. Concatenation of elements is done with the *&* sign.

```
IMAGE( CASE( Risk__c,
"Low", "/img/samples/flag_green.gif",
"Medium", "/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif",
"High", "/img/samples/flag_red.gif",
"/s.gif"), "Competitive Risk") 
& " " & 
CASE( Risk__c,
"Low", "G",
"Medium", "O",
"High", "R",
"Incorrect Risk")
```